# large number is rounded when saving in the database

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

Hi In Oracle PLSQL developer I'm saving a transaction_id as 436478757463572693
But this gets saved as, 4.36478757463573E17.

When I search for the value I do not gat any output.

```
select * from JT_TASK_TRANSACTION_TAB t WHERE TRANSACTION_ID=436478757463572693
```

But when I'm searching like below, I'm getting a record

```
select * from JT_TASK_TRANSACTION_TAB t WHERE TRANSACTION_ID=436478757463573000
```

[image]

How can I get my original value as 436478757463572693 instead of rounded 4.36478757463573E17? Do I need to go something like below.

```
select TO_NUMBER( TRANSACTION_ID, '999999999999999999')
       from TableA
       WHERE TRANSACTION_ID=4.36478757463573E17;
```

But still my output is like below.

[image]

I'm using PLSQL developer. Please help

Data Type of the transaction Id

[image]

Requested output

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: `4.36478757463573E17` is probably the same as `436478757463572693`, just like `.5` and `+0.50` are the same. It's a display problem.

Comment: On a side note, are you positively sure that your transaction ID is meant to be a very big integer? Does it autoincrement? Do you do maths on it?

Comment: Yes... my customer needs to be it a 17 digit number unfortunately. He identifies some differences between site differences with it. For testing purpose, I just edited the transaction_id to a 17 digit number. And got this behavior

Comment: what is the data type of transaction_id?  If it is a number, why are you calling to_number on it?  Or is it a varchar2?

Comment: If the data type is a NUMBER, then this is a display issue in your sql client.  It is not getting saved as xxxE17.  Why are you calling to_number on a column that is already a number?

Comment: From the way you `select` your data, it seems that your `TRANSACTION_ID` got saved as `436478757463573000` instead of `436478757463572693`? Is this the software you are using ( https://www.allroundautomations.com/products/pl-sql-developer/ )?

Comment: yes. I'm using PLSQL Developer

Comment: Please show an output of `select dump(TRANSACTION_ID, 10) from JT_TASK_TRANSACTION_TAB where <filter>` and `select dump(436478757463572693, 10) from dual`

Comment: the output was added

Comment: Please post formatted text not images unless you're showing something specific to the UI; the dump values from the table aren't helpful as we don't know what the real numbers are - only the dump for the single value we're talking about would be useful; what does "I just edited the transaction_id to a 17 digit number" mean - what did you do, and where; [you might be able to change how it's displayed](https://forums.allroundautomations.com/ubb/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Main=10310&Number=38975); and please show exactly how you inserted or updated the value.

Comment: What is the output of `SELECT owner, table_name, column_name, data_type, data_precision, data_scale FROM all_tab_columns t WHERE  column_name = 'TRANSACTION_ID' AND table_name  = 'JT_TASK_TRANSACTION_TAB'` (as **text**, not images)?

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour suggests that the column has a `NUMBER(15,-3)` data type:

```sql
CREATE TABLE JT_TASK_TRANSACTION_TAB (
  TRANSACTION_ID NUMBER(15, -3)
);

INSERT INTO JT_TASK_TRANSACTION_TAB ( transaction_id ) VALUES ( 436478757463572693 );
```

Then `436478757463572693` will be stored with 15 digits of precision and the scale means it will be rounded to the nearest 1000.

The output of:

```sql
SELECT table_name,
       column_name,
       data_type,
       data_precision,
       data_scale
FROM   all_tab_columns t
WHERE  column_name = 'TRANSACTION_ID'
AND    table_name  = 'JT_TASK_TRANSACTION_TAB'
```

is:

| TABLE_NAME | COLUMN_NAME | DATA_TYPE | DATA_PRECISION | DATA_SCALE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| JT_TASK_TRANSACTION_TAB | TRANSACTION_ID | NUMBER | 15 | -3 |

If you do:

```
SELECT *
FROM   JT_TASK_TRANSACTION_TAB
WHERE  transaction_id = 436478757463572693;
```

Then there is no output.

However, casting the input to the same precision and scale:

```
SELECT *
FROM   JT_TASK_TRANSACTION_TAB
WHERE  transaction_id = CAST(436478757463572693 AS NUMBER(15,-3));
```

Outputs:

| TRANSACTION_ID |
| --- |
| 436478757463573000 |

---

> How can I get my original value as 436478757463572693 instead of rounded 4.36478757463573E17? Do I need to go something like below.
>
> ```sql
> select TO_NUMBER( TRANSACTION_ID, '999999999999999999')
>        from TableA
>        WHERE TRANSACTION_ID=4.36478757463573E17;
> ```

`4.36478757463573E17` is scientific notation and is the same as `436478757463573000`.

Do not use `TO_NUMBER` on something that is already a number. `TO_NUMBER( string_value, format_model )` takes a string value as the first argument so you are performing an implicit cast of the number-to-a-string and then explicitly converting string-back-to-number and effectively doing:

```sql
select TO_NUMBER(
         TO_CHAR(TRANSACTION_ID),
         '999999999999999999'
       )
from   TableA
WHERE  TRANSACTION_ID=4.36478757463573E17;
```

If you want to display a number in a specific format then use `TO_CHAR` to convert it to a formatted string:

```sql
select TO_CHAR(
         TRANSACTION_ID,
         '999999999999999999'
       )
from   TableA
WHERE  TRANSACTION_ID=4.36478757463573E17;
```

If you are using a `NUMBER(15,-3)` data type then it is impossible to get back the original number as the scale of `-3` tells the database you only want to store the number to the nearest 1000. The database will not store the hundreds, tens and units digits so there is nothing to "get back".

If you want the data not to be rounded in the table then use `NUMBER(18,0)` instead of `NUMBER(15,-3)`.

```sql
CREATE TABLE JT_TASK_TRANSACTION_TAB (
  TRANSACTION_ID NUMBER(18,0)
);

INSERT INTO JT_TASK_TRANSACTION_TAB ( transaction_id )
VALUES ( 436478757463572693 );
```

Then:

```
SELECT *
FROM   JT_TASK_TRANSACTION_TAB
WHERE  transaction_id = 436478757463572693;
```

Outputs:

| TRANSACTION_ID |
| --- |
| 436478757463572693 |

*Note: if the client application is formatting the numbers using scientific notation then either explicitly format it using `TO_CHAR` or change the settings on your client application.*

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/IAiFW6L3)

Answer (score 2):

you can do one of the following.

```
create table t1 ( fld1 number)
insert into t1(fld1) values( 436478757463572693 )
select to_char(fld1) from t1

IN SQL plus you can do this
col fld1 format 99999999999999999999999999999999999999
```

-- In Toad
View => Toad Options... => Data Grids => Data

You will have some setting in SQL developer, to change the display setting.